# What "little speech" is Niobe referring to?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), Niobe offers Neo her ship to take to the Machine City:

> Niobe: He can take mine.
>
> Roland: You can't do that.
>
> Niobe: Don't try to tell me what I can or cannot do... ...with my ship
> after that **little speech**.

What "*little speech*" is Niobe referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She's referring to what he said a few moments ago, about *his ship being his ship to command*.

> **Roland:** *Bullshit! **While I’m captain of this ship, I say where it has to go.** Believe me, this ship will go to hell long before I let you take it anywhere.*
>
> **Niobe:** *He can take mine.*
>
> **Roland:** *You can’t do that.*
>
> **Niobe:** *Don’t even think of trying to tell me what I can or cannot do with my ship after that little speech.*